# What should I use to Partition a Windows 2003 server?

Tags: windows-server-2003, partition, ibm

I'm trying to partition a Windows 2003 server, and I was wondering what my options are to partition the drive. Currently the 1.9 TB is dedicated to the C:/. We're using an IBM server with a 8 drive array, I can't remember the specific model though. I tried to use partition Magic but I just found out it doesn't do windows 2003 systems. Looking into it I found one of my options is Acronis Partition Expert, but is there any other way I could partition the server (preferably without spending $50)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try booting off a [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/) CD then use [GParted](http://wiki.partedmagic.com/index.php/Using_GParted). Backup first :-)

Comment: I should have known it was the file system that's important not the OS, thank you. I'm going to use this on Monday.

Comment: think because the way the OS was loaded on this particular server (system x 3650) it would not allow the partition table to be changed. I accidentally wiped it while using the disc, after getting impatient of trying to figure out why it wasn't working. So while using the disc designed the load the OS (different for IBM http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/management/serverguide/) I found an option to create a partiton. – killamjr 0 secs ago

Answer (score 0):

Just confirming what AdamB has wrote, GParted is amazing. Used it earlier today without hassle.

If you have Ubuntu Live CD it's on there as well.